# jquery - disabling click function on parent element

Tags: jquery

i have structure like this

```
<table><tr><td></td><td><input type="button" name="button"></td></tr></table>
<script> 
$('tr').click(function(){window.alert('tr');})
$(':input').click(function(){window.alert('input');})
</script>
```

when i click on the button, tr click event also called. is there any way to disable click event on parent element? the only solution i found is to add class to parent element and inside its click function check for it.
 for example:

```
 <script> 
$('tr').click(function(){ if(!$(this).hasClass('disable')) { window.alert('tr');  }  $(this).removeClass('disable');  })
$(':input').click(function(){window.alert('input'); $(this).closest('tr').addClass('disable');})
</script>
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem and it's solution is surprisingly hard to find. Thanks a lot for asking this question and to all the answerers for their contribution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('tr').click(function(){
   window.alert('tr');
});
$(':input').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   window.alert('input');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guK5P/)

Answer (score 3):

.stopPropagation() would work but if you don't want to stop the entire event then you can just fire it if the targets match.

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977552/jquery-how-to-stop-propagation-of-a-bound-function-not-the-entire-event).

Answer (score 2):

Stop Propagation?

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

This will prevent the click event from bubbling through its parents.

Answer (score 0):

You also can check the propagation status using [event.stopimmediatepropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) and [event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()](http://api.jquery.com/event.isImmediatePropagationStopped/)

```
$(':input').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var status = e.isImmediatePropagationStopped();

    //CHECK
    console.log(status); //true-false
});
```